# How to restrict output bandwidth of each stream in RTMP

Tags: nginx, stream, http-live-streaming, rtmp, bandwidth-throttling

I have a digital ocean server for serving RTMP and hls live streaming.Is there any way I can restrict output bandwith for each stream to 1mbps Or 1.5mpbs.

I already tried wondershaper but it is limiting the entire server bandwidth but I need some way to restrict bandwidth only for rtmp and hls streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personaly,I would use either `cgroups` + `tc` or `iptables` for that.

On my servers I have used a tool named `wondersharper`
https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper/blob/master/wondershaper

This can limit the bandwith / throughput on a given network-interface. My NGINX server is listing on a virtual network interface that is limited in its bandwith.

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
```

Another way of doing it (but not tested) are `iptables` and the `hashlimit` extension.

https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html

> hashlimit uses hash buckets to express a rate limiting match (like the limit match) for a group of connections using a single iptables rule. Grouping can be done per-hostgroup (source and/or destination address) and/or per-port. It gives you the ability to express "N packets per time quantum per group" or "N bytes per seconds" (see below for some examples).

```sh
#matching bytes per second flows exceeding 512kbyte/s

--hashlimit-mode srcip,dstip,srcport,dstport --hashlimit-above 512kb/s

#matching bytes per second hosts that exceed 512kbyte/s, but permit up to 1Megabytes without matching

--hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-above 512kb/s --hashlimit-burst 1mb
```

While researching the ipbtables part I found this

[http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/](http://info.iet.unipi.it/%7Eluigi/dummynet/)

Documentation can be found here:\

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ipfw&manpath=FreeBSD+9-current&format=html

That one looks pretty interessting though.

Comment: I tried wondersharper but it is limiting my entire server bandwidth.The thing I need is I am running a RTMP server so I just wanted to rate limit the streaming alone. Thank you for the answers will try using iptable

Comment: Yes this is per interface. I have created a new bridged network interface, configured my fileserver listening on this interface and limited the bandwidth. The other NGINX configuration was listening on the other not-limited interface and proxied the traffic to the limited interface. That just worked great. But yes iptables could do the same without the duplicated interface.